# iPhone - NSSortDescriptor with localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare gives incorrect results for special characters

Tags: iphone, sorting, special-characters, nssortdescriptor, localized

i have a problem with NSSortDescriptor for NSFetchedResultsController (Core Data). I have names stored in the db in Slovenian language (including č ć ž š) and they're not being sorted correctly.

If I only use caseInsensitiveCompare, the names with special chars are put at the end of the table. If I use localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare, the result is almost correct, but is ignoring the special char and comparing it as a normal one.

Example (incorrect):
Slovenia
Šola
Solata
Šopek

Correct:
Slovenia
Solata
Šola
Šopek

Any ideas on how to solve this? Oh, by the way - I have Slovenian language selected in the International -> Region Format part in Settings.

Thanks,
Jure

Comment: Hey Jure, I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late anwser - I ended up using the default sort descriptor - the Contacts app has the same "problem".

Comment: It worked for me, I had some other issue that I recognized later. Otherwise NSSortDescriptor worked fine for me.